# Merging two PHP scripts

Tags: php, mysql

In the 1st code I have a database query fetching information, for example 'name' and display it in a table. Everything works fine.

```
$query = ("SELECT name FROM ...");
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    echo "<tr><td>";
    echo $row['name'];
    echo "</td></tr>\n";
}
```

In 2nd code I'm getting information from external website.

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01;Windows NT 5.0)");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "www.url.com/".$name);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

$data = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

$array = array();
$array = explode(',', $data);
print_r($array);
```

Which displays everything in an array

```
Array
(
    [0] => 30
    [1] => 24986
122
    [2] => 40
    [3] => 227449
....
```

Currently both scripts work in separate php files and I need to define $name manually. However, I would like to join these together and use the **name** obtained from the code #1 database query in the **$name** field in code #2. So far it only gets random data for the array from the website and I'm little lost where/how to input the code. I have not found the proper way to make it work. Any help?

Comment: Put the `curl` in the `while` and use the `$row['name']` in place of `$name`.

Comment: Alternatively, wrap the code in the 2nd file in a `function doMyCode($name){` and then `include` that file from your main file, then call the function and pass the name variable to the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a main php file like follows :

```
<?php

$query = ("SELECT name FROM ...");
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01;Windows NT 5.0)");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "www.url.com/".$row['name']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $array = array();
    $array = explode(',', $data);

    echo "<tr><td>";
        echo $row['name'];
    echo "</td></tr>\n";
    echo "<tr><td>";
        print_r($array); // Display it in the table or do what you want
    echo "</td></tr>\n";
}
```

Like this, you get the array depending on name of the row fetched from your db, and same for each results.

In my example, I append it in the table like you do for the name, but you can do everything with it.

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't realize it was the $row['name'] that had to be used. Everything is working now.

Comment: You're welcome. If you can echo `$row['name']`, you can use it for all you want while it's accessible (in the same script or method) . Don't forgot to mark your question as answered by clicking the green check image at top-left corner of the answer. Also vote the answer as your own appreciation.